# Группировка данных и поля, получаемые из одного и того же столбца

Tags: mysql, sql, if, group-by

Проблема с выборкой информации, *if'ми* делаю выборку 3 полей:

```
IF( таблица_2.id_type=1, таблица_2.value, NULL)'count', 
IF( таблица_2.id_type=2, таблица_2.value, NULL)'country', 
IF( таблица_2.id_type=3, таблица_2.value, NULL)'city'
```

В результате получаются такие наборы данных (отсортировал для удобства):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После группировки получаются поля с NULL.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить положение?

Comment: а что вы хотите?

Comment: Группировку покажите

Comment: @splash58 Хочу что бы вместо null появлялись значения которые стоят в той же позиции итоговая строка должна выглядеть как :

1  31528 1 0 0 3

Comment: Я использую INNER JOIN таблицы 1 с таблицей 2

Answer (score 1):

Придумал решение, вдруг кому пригодится, но работать будет только для числовых значений.

Вместо NULL ставим 0, на конечный результат влиять не может, а другого значения там возникнуть не сможет поскольку есть проверка по id_type. В результате наши конструкции с IF обертываем в SUM и получаем необходимые значения, без их искажения.
Всем спасибо

Comment: Null не повлияет на SUM, можно не менять.

Answer (score 1):

задача — пример типичного обращения с сущностями «ключ-значение».

решить можно по-разному, например, так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74787/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table glavnaja (id int);

create table znachenija (glav int, tip int, znach int);

insert into glavnaja values (1);  

insert into znachenija values
  (1, 1, 10),
  (1, 2, 20),
  (1, 3, 30);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select g.id, z1.znach cnt, z2.znach country, z3.znach city
from glavnaja g, znachenija z1, znachenija z2, znachenija z3
where
  g.id = z1.glav and z1.tip = 1 and
  g.id = z2.glav and z2.tip = 2 and
  g.id = z3.glav and z3.tip = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74787/5/0)**:

```
| id | znach | znach | znach |
|----|-------|-------|-------|
|  1 |    10 |    20 |    30 |
```

Comment: Используйте, пожалуйста, ansi join'ы.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, «зачем платить больше?»

Comment: Этот комментарий не ради дискуссии. Если вам интересно, погуглите. Что касается рекомендации, то в описании метки sql об этом явно указано. Если вам лениво, значит придется делать это другим.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо за информацию.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, посмотрите, пожалуйста: [вот так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74787/6) будет лучше с дидактической точки зрения?

Comment: =) подойдет, правда для EAV логичнее использовать left join.